# Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 because no repositories are defined. Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio

Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 because no repositories are defined.

I have tried a lot of solutions from Stack Overflow but not a single solutions that i mentioned worked for me

Here is my project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they         belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is my app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rsolveapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

After the program sync it gives me this error "Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 because no repositories are defined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding following in "app" level gradle file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar problem and I solved it by adding,

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

To the **buildscript** in **build.gradle(Module:app)** file. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Add the following snippet in build.gradle app level

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

like for example

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}
```